# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Region'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting this error as query does not return column "Regoin". As it depends on user selection. Aggregate function is used in query depending upon user selection. If users does not select Region the column needs to be hidden. How can I achieve this.

Stored Procedure

```
     begin
    set @SQLQuery='select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BusinessUnit) As SrNo, BusinessUnit'
set @GrpBy=''       /* This is to concatenate as group by clause */

    if @Tower<>'false'
        begin
        set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ', ' + 'Tower'
        Set @GrpBy = @GrpBy + ', ' + 'Tower'
        end

    if @Regionwise<>'false'
        begin
        set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ', ' + 'Region'
        Set @GrpBy = @GrpBy + ', ' + 'Region'
        end

    if @Countrywise<>'false'
        begin
        set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ', ' + 'Country'
        Set @GrpBy = @GrpBy + ', ' + 'Country'
        end

    if @Levelwise<>'false'
        begin
        set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ', ' + 'EmployeeLevel'
        Set @GrpBy = @GrpBy + ', ' + 'EmployeeLevel'
        end


    Set @SQLQuery= @SQLQuery + ', count(SapId) as EmpCount from tbl_RosterMgmtData where RollOffDate is null '

    Set @SQLQuery= @SQLQuery + ' group by BusinessUnit' + @GrpBy

end



Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQuery
```

Repeater

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><asp:Literal ID="Literal11" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SrNo") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:Literal ID="Literal12" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BusinessUnit") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td align="left" id="td_Tower" runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="Literal15" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tower") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:Literal ID="Literal16" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:Literal ID="Literal17" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:Literal ID="Literal13" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpCount") %>' Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal></td>

        </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you expect anybody to be able to help here? The error message is pretty clear. You are dynamically changing the columns returned from your procedure and it is abundantly clear that your dotnet code can't handle this. It is expecting a column to be in the result set of your procedure. You need to share a LOT more information here, the problem is only partly in your procedure.

Comment: @sean-lange   So it wont work. What can be the alternative way??

Comment: There could be a number of options. But they depend on what you need to accomplish. You could allow dynamic binding, you could always return the columns and then conditionally hide them. There are surely other options but those both come to mind quickly.